# Is fclose needed when fopen has failed?

Tags: c++, c

consider the below code snippet.

```
{
....
FILE *fptr = fopen("file_that_does_not_exist","r");
...
}
```

here, if fopen fails, do we still need to call fclose() for some cleanup ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its simple friend, i mean just imagine.... Do you have to shutdown a computer even if it fails to boot up.... :D

> Just the same way you don't need to
>   close a file which you actually never
>   opened.

Some extra tip : fclose is used just for the sake of freeing the file so that it could be used by some other application or module, as it is not a sharable resource.
Also, fclose means you now free the pointer you were using and can use it for any other file.

Answer (score 19):

No, since fopen() returns 0, which is an invalid file handle. fclose() may even crash if you try to do this.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not necessary. You didn't open anything in the first place, so you don't need to close it.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot close doors that are not opened. If succeeds, `fopen` returns pointer to the open file and only makes sense to pass this value to `fclose`.